# Change generated TextBlock with generated TextBox on Double Click

Tags: c#, wpf

Im generating cards for each item from the database.
Now I want to add a edit function. So I want, that if I double click on a TextBlock, it changes to TextBox and has the same Content.

My Code until now is:

```
private void TextBlock_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && e.ClickCount == 2)
        {
            string test = (sender as TextBlock).Text;
            (sender as TextBlock).Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

            TextBox descContentBox = new TextBox();
            descContentBox.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
            descContentBox.Text = test;
            descContentBox.Opacity = .68;

        }
    }
```

But I guess this will not work. Because Im generating the TextBlock etc. in another Function.

My second try is:

```
private void LoadRoles()
  [...]
   TextBlock descContent = new TextBlock();
   descContent.Opacity = .68;
   descContent.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
   descContent.Text = reader[2].ToString();

  TextBox descContentBox = new TextBox();
  descContentBox.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
  descContentBox.Text = descContent.Text;
  descContentBox.Opacity = .68;
  descContentBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

And then change the Visibility in the MouseDown Event. But then I have the problem that I dont know how to detect descContentBox. I detect descContent with (sender as TextBlock). But How to detect the generated Hidden descContentBox ?

So there have to be another solution. Any ideas ?

Comment: You're creating new `TextBox` but not attaching this into your "holder" ( a parent control ).

Comment: Yea because my holder ( a generated StackPanel ) is defined in the LoadRoles Method. So I cant access to it from the MouseDown event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TextBlock` is located in some kind of parent panel. You could get a reference to this one and add the `TextBox` to it, e.g.:

```
private void TextBlock_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && e.ClickCount == 2)
    {
        TextBlock txt = sender as TextBlock;
        Panel panel = txt.Parent as Panel;
        if (panel != null)
        {
            txt.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            int index = panel.Children.IndexOf(txt);

            TextBox descContentBox = new TextBox();
            descContentBox.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
            descContentBox.Text = "test";
            descContentBox.Opacity = .68;
            panel.Children.Insert(index, descContentBox);
        }

    }
}
```

The above sample should work if the `TextBlock` is located directly in a `Panel` such as a `Grid` or a `StackPanel`:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown" Text="edit..." />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: The problem is, that the StackPanel is generated too.
The Code is too long but here is my code of which Controls are generated:
https://pastebin.com/HrPs9RVU

Comment: So? What difference does it make whether the StackPanel is "generated"?

Comment: Oh Sorry. It's early in the morning and I dont checked ur code. Nvm it works now thx for your help :)